# Open & close database transaction VS global variables

Tags: c#, sql-server, global-variables

I develop an application in Visual Studio (C# .Net), that reads data from a database (SQL server), the user can edit selected data through several forms and update the database. In many cases, I open transaction with database so as to select data and sometimes I execute the same query many times because I need it in several forms. The question is : When running a program is it better to open and close the transaction with the database over and over again or to select all data when initializing, create global variables will all the data needed and connect to database just on update?

Comment: That depends on how often you're going to be doing it.  if you're doing it once every hour, then thats fine, if you're doing it 100 times a minute, that would seem overkill.

Comment: It also depends on the total amount of data passed between the database and the application, and the amount of data that is expected to be consumed / updated by the users.

Comment: In my view that's not good, Open and Close connection again and again continuously. It will affect performance of your application. The better way is write an `Stored Procedure` and write your logic in it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, If you do a lot of reading / editing, global variables might be a good idea. If you only read/edit a few thingsw a day, just standard connections are fine. Also, if you use global variables, remember that if someone edits the database from outside your program, you wont see the edit until your reload the database into the global variables